# The argument type 'AssetGenImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter gen package to To initialize an image

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image(image: Assets.images.logo, height: 64),//error is here
              const SizedBox(
                height: 32,
              ),
              const SpinKitFadingCube(
                color: Solidcolors.primaryColor,
                size: 32.0,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the error:

> The argument type 'AssetGenImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

here is my generated file :

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

    class $AssetsImagesGen {
    const $AssetsImagesGen();

    /// File path: assets/images/logo.png
     AssetGenImage get logo => const 
     AssetGenImage('assets/images/logo.png');
     }

     class Assets {
      Assets._();

      static const $AssetsImagesGen images = 
      $AssetsImagesGen();
      }``
```

Comment: is it the full gen class ? I think it might be an issue while generating file, try latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the README.md of flutter_gen. Please refer to this section:

> Usage Example
> FlutterGen generates Image class if the asset is Flutter supported
> image format.
>
> Example results of assets/images/chip.jpg:
>
> Assets.images.chip is an implementation of AssetImage class.
> Assets.images.chip.image(...) returns Image class.
> Assets.images.chip.provider(...) returns ImageProvider class.    <--- ANSWER HERE
> Assets.images.chip.path just returns the path string.
> Assets.images.chip.values just returns the values list.

So in the OP's code `Assets.images.logo.provider()` should fix the problem without having to edit the generated code (definitely not recommended).

Feels a bit clunky, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Just use as `Assets.logo.image()`, it provides image itself.

```dart
 children: [
       Assets.logo.image(height:64),
```

Right part will be generated

```dart
/// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND
/// *****************************************************
///  FlutterGen
/// *****************************************************

// coverage:ignore-file
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering,unnecessary_import

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Assets {
  Assets._();
  static const AssetGenImage logo = AssetGenImage('assets/logo.jpg');

}

class AssetGenImage {
  const AssetGenImage(this._assetName);

  final String _assetName;

  Image image({
    Key? key,
    AssetBundle? bundle,
    ImageFrameBuilder? frameBuilder,
    ImageErrorWidgetBuilder? errorBuilder,
    String? semanticLabel,
    bool excludeFromSemantics = false,
    double? scale,
    double? width,
    double? height,
    Color? color,
    Animation<double>? opacity,
    BlendMode? colorBlendMode,
    BoxFit? fit,
    AlignmentGeometry alignment = Alignment.center,
    ImageRepeat repeat = ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
    Rect? centerSlice,
    bool matchTextDirection = false,
    bool gaplessPlayback = false,
    bool isAntiAlias = false,
    String? package,
    FilterQuality filterQuality = FilterQuality.low,
    int? cacheWidth,
    int? cacheHeight,
  }) {
    return Image.asset(
      _assetName,
      key: key,
      bundle: bundle,
      frameBuilder: frameBuilder,
      errorBuilder: errorBuilder,
      semanticLabel: semanticLabel,
      excludeFromSemantics: excludeFromSemantics,
      scale: scale,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      color: color,
      opacity: opacity,
      colorBlendMode: colorBlendMode,
      fit: fit,
      alignment: alignment,
      repeat: repeat,
      centerSlice: centerSlice,
      matchTextDirection: matchTextDirection,
      gaplessPlayback: gaplessPlayback,
      isAntiAlias: isAntiAlias,
      package: package,
      filterQuality: filterQuality,
      cacheWidth: cacheWidth,
      cacheHeight: cacheHeight,
    );
  }

  String get path => _assetName;

  String get keyName => _assetName;
}
```

Comment: its not working,it shows this error: The expression dosnt evaluate to a function, so it cant be invoked.

Comment: are you using inside column ?

Comment: yes,im using inside column

Comment: Can you include your generated file

Comment: i include that to my question

Comment: check update one

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and restart the ide then rebuild the and what is the current error and how you've include on asset file inside pubspec.yaml